# Find value by key permutations, php

Tags: php, permutation

I have many combinations of different genes types. Each combination has its value. I want to find value by the combination.

**Note:**

Switched letters are the same. Example: 'CT' = 'TC', 'AG' = 'GA', etc.

I solve this now by converting letters to numbers and compare its sums. See my code, please.

Is it a good approach?
Should I change my data structure? ($map)

```
<?php

function toNum($string)
{
  $map = [
    'A' => 1,
    'C' => 2,
    'G' => 3,
    'T' => 4,
  ];

  $arr = str_split($string);
  $r   = 0;

  foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (!isset($map[$value])) {
      continue;
    }

    $r += $map[$value];
  }

  return $r;
}

function getValue($map, $input)
{
  foreach ($map as $row => $key) {
    $current_row = $row;

    $row     = explode(',', $row);
    $attempt = 0;

    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
      if (toNum($row[$key]) === toNum($input[$key])) {
        $attempt++;
      }
    }

    if ($attempt === count($row)) {
      return $map[$current_row];
    }
  }
}

$map = [
  'CC,GG,AA,CC' => 'high',
  'TT,AG,TT,CG' => 'medium',
  'CT,AG,TT,GG' => 'low',
];

echo getValue($map, ['CC', 'GG', 'AA', 'CC']) . "\n"; // high
echo getValue($map, ['TT', 'AG', 'TT', 'CG']) . "\n"; // medium
echo getValue($map, ['TT', 'GA', 'TT', 'GC']) . "\n"; // medium
echo getValue($map, ['CT', 'AG', 'TT', 'GG']) . "\n"; // low

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it quite a bit simpler by computing the correct map key given your input, without changing your structure.

```
function sortString($string)
{
  $type_chars = str_split($string);
  sort($type_chars);
  return implode($type_chars);
}

function getValue($map, $input)
{
  $key = implode(',', array_map('sortString', $input));
  return $map[$key] ?? null;
}
```

Note that the last line is PHP7 only. If you're not running it, you can replace it with:

```
return isset($map[$key]) ? $map[$key] : null;
```

Then you order your map's keys using the same callback:

```
function sortMap($map)
{
  return array_reduce(array_keys($map), function ($sorted_map, $types) use ($map) {
    $sorted_types = preg_replace_callback('/[A-Z]{2}/', function ($matches) {
      return sortString($matches[0]);
    }, $types);
    $sorted_map[$sorted_types] = $map[$types];
    return $sorted_map;
  }, []);
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/4HhsV**

Comment: Nice solution, but what if have combination without right order? Like 'CT,**GA**,TT,GG';

Comment: Well I thought GA and AG were the same thing? Is it a problem to always have them with the "first" letter first? Otherwise, let me know and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. GA and AG is the same thing, but if in $map I will have GA, not AG - your solution will not work. 

Generally speaking, it's not a problem, but I want to achieve a solution
where I will not care too much about my $map.

Comment: There you go. Bit more code this way obviously, but since I'm unsure how much the structure can be changed, it's probably as short as you can get with the current one.

Comment: Thank you a lot ) Nice solution.